# Detailed explanation of =IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($B$2:$B2=B2))>1,0,1)?

Tags: excel

I need to count unique values in Excel Pivot 2010. I tried the approach [from here](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot07.html#Unique)

But I do not understand how this formula works `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($B$2:$B2=B2))>1,0,1)`

**`SUMPRODUCT` accepts array arguments, however `$A$2:$A2=A2` is boolean .**

1 ) Let's assume `$A$2:$A2=A2` is TRUE and `$B$2:$B2=B2` is FALSE, then does it become `SUMPRODUCT(TRUE * FALSE )` OR `SUMPRODUCT (1 * 0 )`

2)  I tried a random table

```
      A     B
1    year   id
2    1990    1
3    1991    2
4    1992    3
```

I tried using this formula `=A1:B4=2` and it threw an error ? So why does not `$A$2:$A10=A10` throws an error and what does it exactly mean?

Comment: since 1=True and 0=False : ´(TRUE * FALSE )==(1*0)´; both ($A$2:$A2=A2) AND  $B$2:$B2=B2 must be true, to find unique valuse;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($B$2:$B2=B2))>1,0,1)
```

> Let's assume `$A$2:$A2=A2` is `TRUE` and `$B$2:$B2=B2` is `FALSE`

You get: `SUMPRODUCT(TRUE*FALSE)` which then is interpreted by excel to be `SUMPRODUCT(1*0)`, becoming `0`.

When you drag the formula now, let's say, one cell down, the references will become:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A3=A3)*($B$2:$B3=B3))>1,0,1)
```

And you get array results. Let's say now that you drag it once more:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A4=A4)*($B$2:$B4=B4))>1,0,1)
```

And let's say that A2 = A3 <> A4 and B2 = B3 = B4. You get:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT({FALSE, FALSE, TRUE}*{TRUE, TRUE, TRUE})>1,0,1)
```

Which becomes:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT({0, 0, 1}*{1, 1, 1})>1,0,1)
```

This becomes:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT({0, 0, 1})>1,0,1)
```

`SUMPRODUCT({0, 0, 1})` is 1.

The whole formula thus returns 0.

`1` will be returned only when either the last cell in the column A, or in column B is different from the first cell (and if the range is only 1 cell big).

---

**EDIT:**

As to your example, array formulas outside array functions tend to either return the first value, or a value depending on what row/column it is, or plainly an error.

What you can do to check the results is to press <kbd>F2</kbd> on the cell with the error, and then press <kbd>F9</kbd>. For your example, you should get something like:

```
{FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE; FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Did you mean `And let's say that A2 = A3 <> A4 and B2 = B3 = B4. You get:

=IF(SUMPRODUCT({FALSE, FALSE, TRUE}*{TRUE, TRUE, TRUE})>1,0,1) ` ... We compare A4 with each element in the `A2:A4` right?

Comment: @AzamatBagatov Oops, good catch, I guess I was thinking about something else there ^^;